# View function template instantiations

Tags: c++, templates, g++

I have a simple function template:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
T GetMax (T a, T b) {
  T result;
  result = (a > b) ? a : b;
  return (result);
}

int main () {
  cout << GetMax<int>(5, 6) << endl;
  cout << GetMax<long>(10, 5) << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

The above example will generate 2 function template instantiations, one for *int* and another for *long*. Is there any g++ option to view the function template instantiations?

Comment: I usually try hard to refrain from editing intended content, but if you give a mouse a cookie..  While, ironically, I left syntax which I can't stand, it was the 'cpp' tag (which means "C preprocessor" instead of "C++") that prompted the edit; but the big change was to use 'instantiation', which is the term the standard uses for "generating" those.

Comment: Thanks Roger for the comment. I will follow your tips.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `nm` program (part of [binutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/binutils/)) to see the list of symbols used by your program.  For example:

```
$ g++ test.cc -o test
$ nm test | grep GetMax
00002ef0 T __Z6GetMaxIiET_S0_S0_
00002f5c T __Z6GetMaxIiET_S0_S0_.eh
00002f17 T __Z6GetMaxIlET_S0_S0_
00002f80 T __Z6GetMaxIlET_S0_S0_.eh
```

I don't know why each one has two copies, one with a `.eh` suffix, but otherwise you can tell that this particular function was instantiated twice.  If you version of `nm` supports the `-C/--demangle` flag, you can use that to get readable names:

```
$ nm --demangle test | grep GetMax
00002ef0 T int GetMax<int>(int, int)
00002f5c T _Z6GetMaxIiET_S0_S0_.eh
00002f17 T long GetMax<long>(long, long)
00002f80 T _Z6GetMaxIlET_S0_S0_.eh
```

If that option isn't supported, you can use [`c++filt`](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.16/binutils/c_002b_002bfilt.html) to demangle them:

```
$ nm test | grep GetMax | c++filt
00002ef0 T int GetMax<int>(int, int)
00002f5c T __Z6GetMaxIiET_S0_S0_.eh
00002f17 T long GetMax<long>(long, long)
00002f80 T __Z6GetMaxIlET_S0_S0_.eh
```

So, you can see that `GetMax` was instantiated with `int` and `long` respectively.

Answer (score 1):

If you have the linker generate a map file, you can see the names of all generated symbols.  Some parsing with grep/perl may get you what you want.  The names will be mangled.

This command line worked for me:

```
g++ -o test -Wl,-map,test.map test.cpp
```

test.map will be generated.

This might be further down the pipeline than you're looking for though.

Comment: Another option is the nm program, which is part of binutils and thus should be available on any platform in which GCC is available.